# Add to selection Shortcut, not modifier

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I have a question about the "add to..." and "subtract from..." button options when using selection tools in Photoshop.

#### I understand a few things:

1. PS will make a new selection by default
2. *Holding* Shift or Alt/Opt will add to or remove from selection temporarily (as long as the modifier is held down)
3. One can click on the options in the tool panel to add to/remove from the selection to avoid holding the modifiers down.

#### My question:

Is there a keyboard shortcut that is the equivalent of clicking the add/remove options in the tool panel? In other words, instead of using the shortcut of press/hold shift/alt to modify your selection mode, is there a key *press* that activates those modes, without having to *hold* the modifier?

Comment: The full list of the default Adobe Photoshop shortcuts is published on [this Adobe help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html). Download the PDF from the link on that page.

Comment: I dont think its possible. But you may try if script listener sees the mode change if it does then you can do it via a script and then force that as a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a bit of an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) ... not necessarily about any tool functionality - or lack thereof -  but more about the workflow.

---

The biggest issue is that if you need the add/subtract to be sticky.... you are probably selecting things *inefficiently*. The add/subtract is *meant* to be a momentary thing for the selection tools. I do not believe there's any way to make the add/subtract "stick" without holding down the modifier keys.

*Example of a more effective workflow:*
If you need something more "sticky," an easy thing would be to toggle **[Quick Mask Mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-temporary-quick-mask.html)** by tapping the <kbd>q</kbd> key. You then have "sticky" add/subtract essentially... as well as the ability to use any number of tools to further refine a selection.

.. or use a layer mask...

... or use the Pen Tool...

.. or use Channels ...

.. etc....

Answer (score -3):

Customize the keyboard shortcuts in Photoshop to create your shortcut for the "add to selection" and "subtract from selection" options. Here's how you can do it:

Go to "Edit" in the menu bar and choose "Keyboard Shortcuts" (or use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K on Windows or Command+Option+Shift+K on Mac).
In the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box, select the "Tools" option in the "Shortcuts For" dropdown menu.
Expand the "Select & Mask" category.
Look for the "Add To Selection" and "Subtract From Selection" options.
Assign your preferred keyboard shortcuts to these options by clicking on the corresponding empty box and entering your desired key combination.
By customizing the keyboard shortcuts, you can create your own shortcuts that directly activate the "add to selection" and "subtract from selection" modes with a single key press.

Comment: Chat GPT?? .....`:)`

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question.  The OP is not asking how to change the shortcuts. Read the question again.

Comment: This does actually work, but only in select & mask itself. Default key is E.

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure if this does the trick. Also, @tetsujin, I don't think that works either. E is for eraser. And this question has nothing to do with chat GPT.

**IF** changing the shortcut allows for the "Add to" to latch, that would totally work. End goal is to use my stream deck to add a button. Sadly they don't do held keys, otherwise my problem would be solved!

Comment: @rgbrobot I posted about ChatGPT because, to me, *clearly* this answer was generated by ChatGPT's AI - as opposed to a knowledgable user aware of how the application actually functions. *Many* would-be reputation hunters are relying on ChatGPT to answer questions they could never answer themselves.

Comment: @rgbrobot - it only works in select & mask. It's another case of ChatGPT getting the wrong end of the stick & rather than telling you it can't be done, finds something a close approximation of the truth & tells you that instead.